# R: Error on ggplot2 in not allowing me to plot the graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

*please help me fix this error. Not sure why R can't read my column names, take the columns and plot the scatter plot*

```
library(ggplot2)

y1 <- data2[,"Average Weekly Workplace Earnings 2016  (Â£)"]

chart <- ggplot(data = data2, aes(x = data2[,"CO2 Emissions per Capita 2016  (tons)"], y = data2[,"Average Weekly Workplace Earnings 2016  (Â£)"]))
chart + geom_point()`
```

*This is the error message*
    `> chart <- ggplot(data = data2, aes(x = data2[,"CO2 Emissions per Capita 2016  (tons)"], y =   data2[,"Average Weekly Workplace Earnings 2016  (Â£)"]))

> chart + geom_point()
>       Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type spec_tbl_df/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame.     Defaulting to continuous.
>       Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type spec_tbl_df/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame. Defaulting to continuous.
>       Error in is.finite(x) : default method not implemented for type 'list'
>       `

Answer (score 1):

the aes function is working in the way that you only have to pass the names of the columns not the complete columns themself so
instead of:

```
chart <- ggplot(data = data2, aes(x = data2[,"CO2 Emissions per Capita 2016  (tons)"], y = data2[,"Average Weekly Workplace Earnings 2016  (Â£)"]))
```

try:

```
chart <- ggplot(data = data2, aes(x = `CO2 Emissions per Capita 2016  (tons)`, y = `Average Weekly Workplace Earnings 2016  (Â£)`))
```

please not that I switched the quotation from normal `"` to ` this makes it an object instead of a string

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!